# How to delete tagged files in S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3

I got 116 files in my s3 folder in which few are tagged.now i want to delete all the tagged files.
key is `TAG` value is `True`

i have used below command which is not working.

```
aws s3 rm s3://bucket/folder1/folder2--recursive --query Contents[].[Key]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think s3 command does not support bulk deletion by tag.

You can only specify a kind of pattern if you have it:

```
aws s3 rm s3://mybucket/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "yourpattern*"
```

To delete by tag, you can look into delete-object method in s3api - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-objects.html

And run it in dryrun mode to avoid bad surprises ;)

Comment: I dont want to delete specific file. want to delete files having tags.. any suggestions ? gone through docs but no luck

Comment: I believe this is actually not supported, I am sorry :)

Comment: What you could do, is to implement a fro cycle listing all object, and checking for tags using "get-object-tagging" method - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-object-tagging.html. Then, if the object contain the key:value, delete it by key using "delete-object" https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/delete-object.html

Comment: Not really straightforward, but should do the job!